# How to send data to the database in a transparent way to the user in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, database

I have a text field `"Add to Newsletter your mail"` and a button `"Send"` in my page which purpose is to collect the email of the user and add it to the list of my newsletter if the user presses the button.
What i want is to add the email to my db if the user taps the button and show an alert "Your mail has been added to the newsletter" possibly *without* having to change page.
Till now i've called a php file as the button was pressed, execute there the code to add the mail to the db and then redirected to the main page. It works, but i think there'a better and more correct way to do it in jquery... There's one?

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "ajax", there are no shortage of tutorials out there - with and without jQuery.

Comment: `'ajax'` with method `'post'` i think.

Comment: There's no doubt there are tutorials, but it's a bit difficult to choose a tutorial when you are not sure what you're looking for... Thank you Jai, i didn't know about the function ajax ^^

Comment: @ElisabettaFalivene — That's why I told you what you needed to look for!

Comment: Sorry Quentin, i've stupidly linked the observation to the first downvote, reading it as a subtle critic, which it wasn't mean to. ^^'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax on button press to save it to database.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#button_id').onclick(function(){
   email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url : 'save_email.php',
        data:{email_val:email},
            success:function(data){
                      alert(data);
                }
  });

})
```

Comment: yea, i'd be glad to know, too. I didn't know about the function ajax. Thanks a lot for the example code!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ajax process to send the data in the background of the webpage.
try to see : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery AJAX` is what you are looking for. Send data to PHP using `.ajax()` and get the response back and display the acknowledgement text.

[More Info](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @downvoter: A downvote without a comment is not appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to send the email to server, and show the alert in ajax response.

using jQuery, you can use: `$.ajax` or a variation such as `$.post`

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/